# XRay-Import json result file with Cloud Rest API call getting error "No project could be found with key 'null'."

Tags: jira-xray

We are trying to import test execution result in json format to xray Jira cloud by cloud Rest API call. After importing through Rest API call we are getting below error.
I gone through the solutions but couldn't got working solution.

{"error": "Error retrieving Project from Jira with key "null": No project could be found with key 'null'."}

Below is my code snippet:

```
public void postAPICall(){
    File dataFile = new File("src/main/resources/Payloads/auth.json");
    String url ="https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/authenticate";
    RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();
    request.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.body(dataFile);
    Response response = request.post(url);
    ResponseBody body = response.getBody();
    tokenResult=body.asString();
}

@Test
public void postCallUpdateTestResult(){
    postAPICall();
    File jsonDataInFile = new File("src/main/resources/Payloads/SimpleExecutionResult.json");
    String url ="https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/import/execution?testExecKey=XX-XX";
    RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();
    request.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    request.header("Authorization", "Bearer "+tokenResult.substring(1,(tokenResult.length()-1)));
    request.body(jsonDataInFile);
    Response response = request.post(url);
    ResponseBody body = response.getBody();
    System.out.println(body.asString());
}
```

auth.json

{
"client_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"client_secret": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}

SimpleExecutionResult.json

{
"testExecutionKey": "XX-XX",
"tests": [
{
"testKey": "XX-XX",
"status": "FAILED"
},
{
"testKey": "XX-XX",
"status": "PASSED"
}
]
}

Comment: This means that the project key was not found in the results submitted.

The supported Json import are Xray Json, Behave Json or Cucumber Json, are you  generating one of these?

Please make sure in your replacements you are filling correctly the values.

More info here: https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Import+Execution+Results+-+REST#ImportExecutionResultsREST-ImportingExecutionResults

Comment: Can you please try to identify the project key on the JSON content? (not as query parameter) . See example at: https://github.com/Xray-App/xray-code-snippets/blob/main/use_cases/import_automation_results/python/xray_cloud.json

Comment: I am using Xray Json I added Project key in query perm with end point but still same error. Below is my URL.
https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/import/execution?testExecKey=XX-XX&projectKey=XX

We Tried with below Json too but no luck

{
  "testExecutionKey": "XX",
    "info" : {
        "project" : "XX"
  },
  "tests": [
    {
      "testKey": "XX",
      "status": "PASSED"
    },
    {
      "testKey": "XXX",
      "status": "PASSED"
    },
    {
      "testKey": "XXX",
      "status": "PASSED"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: It must be something with the issue keys. You may remove the "testExecutionKey" element on the json. You may try the code snippet that I shared earlier, change the keys to fit your use case. The format you shared seems fine. If your project key  is "CALC", then use that for the "project" element. then for the tests, the "testKey" should be something like CALC-123 .

Comment: Were you able to solve it @ClincherSparton?

Comment: Yes below error is resolved after adding project key in json

{"error": "Error retrieving Project from Jira with key "null": No project could be found with key 'null'."}

But now new error  while importing using Rest API i.e below

{"error":"Test with key XX-XX not found."}

Comment: do you have permissions to view the Test with that key in Jira?

Comment: @Sérgio  Yes I have permission to view Test with the key in Jira.